# Overriding methods and weird behavior

Tags: java, inheritance, overriding, overloading

I have 2 classes, one which extends the second one and overrides some of the methods of the parent. When I call `fs.m(ff)` I got a weird result, and I can't figure out why does it happen. type `First fs` shouldn't have access to class Second methods, even if we assigned a new Second object to them, unless we casted it like that - `(Second) fs.m(ff)`. Could anyone please explain why does this code produce output "override"?

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        First ff = new First();
        First fs = new Second();
        Second ss = new Second();

        System.out.println( fs.m(ff));
    }
}


public class First {
    public String m(First x){
        return "default";
    }

    public String m(First x, First y){
        return "default";
    }
}

public class Second extends First{
    public String m(Second x){
        return "overload";
    }

    public String m(First x){
        return "override";
    }

    public String m(First x, Second y){
        return "???";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The method invoked for `fs.m(ff)` is determined by the runtime type of `fs`. That runtime type is `Second`, and since `Second` overrides the `public String m(First x)` method, that method is executed.

`fs` has access do the methods declared in `First` class, since it is of type `First`, but during runtime, the actual methods that get executed depend on whether those methods are overridden by the run-time type of the instance assigned to `fs`, which is `Second`.

Answer (score 0):

Fs is actually pointing a Second Object (fs is a reference to an object of type Second).
So when you call  fs.m(ff) it is actually calling the object on Second due to dynamic binding (override).